# RE2 (Rust) regular expression doesn't work as expected

Tags: regex, rust

I have a regex that seemingly is straightforward but does not act as required. The input to be parsed is described as follows (nb: {} are not part of the regex, only what's inside):

- A sequence of 0 or more spaces {\s*}
- A dash {-}
- A sequence of 0 or more spaces {\s*}
- A full person's name (first name, middle names, surname; all captured into f1). The name must not start with a number
  must appear at the end of the line {[A-Za-z][\w\s]*)}

The whole construct SPACE-SPACEf1 is optional

Just to explain what is captured into f1:
For the first char, I'm using the set of chars represented by [A-Za-z]. Followed by \w or space 0 or more times. This is captured into f1.

```
(?:\s*-\s*(?P<f1>[A-Za-z][\w\s]*))?$
```

I expect the following sequences to match and capture a value into f1:

- " - Bruce"      (f1=Bruce)
- " - Bruce Dickinson"      (f1=Bruce Dickinson)

I expect the following to not match:

- "Bruce"         (there is no leading dash)
- " - Bruce!"     (there is a non word (\w) character after the name and before end of line

I expect the following match but not capture a value into f1 (I would prefer it to not match though):

- " - 1Bruce"     (leading character is numeric)

These are the actual results:

- " - Bruce"      (f1=Bruce) Tick; this works
- " - Bruce Dickinson"      (f1=Bruce Dickinson) Tick; this works
- "Bruce"         (f1= not captured, but expression is a match. This is wrong, because Bruce doesn't match the optional part, and $ comes next which doesn't match Bruce)
- " - Bruce!"     (f1= not cpatured, but expression is a match; this is wrong, because of the !, which means that match does not appear at the end of line.

I expect that:

```
(?:\s*-\s*(?P<f1>[A-Za-z][\w\s]*))?
```

would consume { - Bruce}, which should leave !, which should fail because of the next regex token being $; however, the computer says no, so I'm wrong but I don't know why :(

- " - 1Bruce"     (f1= not captured, but expression is match. This is understandable because the whole {space dash space f1} sequence is optional and because it doesn't match, that construct is skipped and then there is nothing else to process on the input; we hit the end of line)

If I can get this to work, I can get the rest of my expression to work the way I want it to. I need somebody else to jolt me into thinking about this differently. I've spent 2 days on  this with no positive output, so very frustrating.

PS: I am using regex101.com to test regexes. The regexes will be used as part of a Rust application whose regex engine is based on google's RE2.

Eventually, I need to be able to recognise a sequence of names delimited by &, and the whole expression is optional by the use of ? and must appear at the end of line $.

So

- { - Bruce & Nicko & Dave Murray } would be valid

and

- { - Bruce & Nicko & Dave Murray & } should not be valid and NOT match

But 1 step at a time!

Comment: It would be nice if you include the actual code that we can run to test.

Comment: I havent got any code. I am testing it in regex101.com. When I get this working, then I'll roll it into code, but thats the easy part.

Comment: If it helps, I can write a unit test and post that if thats better?

Comment: Do you intend to make the whole regex optional? That means that the empty string matches, so every input will match (it matches a string of length zero before the end of the line `$`).

Comment: Well actually, that's why I use the $ anchor to prevent any string from matching. If I'm wrong, how should I fix it?

Comment: I think you are wrong with your assumptions about the *optional* character of the whole pattern. Make it obligatory: `\s*-\s*(?P<f1>[A-Za-z][\w\s]*)$`, or even unroll the grouping as [`\s*-\s*(?P<f1>[^\W\d_]\w*(?:\s+\w+)*)$`](https://regex101.com/r/mZ1uG9/3)

Comment: I can't make \s*-\s* obligatory independent of the rest, because that would allow a dash, without a name following it, which is not what is required. However, I have tried your regex, and it works better than mine. I am going to crawl under a rock for a while and think about why it works better than mine, but so far so good. I need to test it on more inoput too, so thanks

Comment: Also, Wiktor, I'm trying to force a change in the way I'm writing regexes, because I keep making the same type of mistakes,hence, me crawling under a rock :)

Comment: No, `\s*-\s*` is not the only obligatory pattern: the first letter is also obligatory. See this [`\s*-\s*(?P<f1>([^\W\d_])\w*(?:\s+\w+)*)(?:\s*&\s*(?P<f2>([^\W\d_])\w*(?:\s+\w+)*))*$`](https://regex101.com/r/mZ1uG9/4) whole regex. Please add more test cases if it does not work.

Comment: Ah yes, I see what you mean ...

Comment: Wiktor, If you post your version of the regex as an answer, ie this one that recognises 2 names, then I can mark it as the solution. It does just what I was looking for, and confirms to me that my thinking of the optionality is wrong. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The point here is that you cannot match and not match something at the same time. If you make the whole pattern optional, and the end of string obligatory, even if there is nothing of interest the end of string will be matched - always.

The way out is to think of a subpattern you are interested in. You are interested in the names, so, make the first letter obligatory. The hyphen seems to be obligatory in all test cases you supplied, too. Everything else can be optional:

```
\s*-\s*(?P<f1>([^\W\d_])\w*(?:\s+\w+)*)(?:\s*&\s*(?P<f2>([^\W\d_])\w*(?:\s+\w+‌​)*))*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mZ1uG9/4) (the `\s` is replaced with `\h` and `\n` added to the negated character classes just for demo purposes as it is  a multiline demo).

Note that I replaced `[a-zA-Z]` with `[^\W\d_]` to make the pattern more flexible (`[^\W\d_]` just matches any letter).

Comment: Glad to help. When you write regex patterns, try to *be* the regex engine: follow the linear logic first: match this, capture this, do not match this... up to... end. The current pattern looks horrid (maybe it is) but it is quite linear and efficient. Short patterns do not always turn out the most efficient, BTW.